# Delete Button that deletes several controls

Tags: c#, button, controls

I am trying to implement a delete button that deletes several other controls such as `textbox` and `combobox` that are related to the button. Right now, I succeeded only by deleting one control by using `tag` function as follows:

```
private void deleteControl(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
   Button btn = (Button)sender;

   TextBox txtbox = (TextBox)this.Controls.Find(btn.Tag.ToString(), true)[0];
   txtbox.Dispose();
}
```

The above code is a code snippet from my function that I implemented. However, I only can delete 1 `Control` by using this method since I only can tag one `Control` to my delete `button`. So how should I implement if I want to delete 2 controls using a delete `button`?

Comment: so you want a tag with multiple button assignmets?

Comment: You are only accessing the first control. If you want to delete all controls you can get all controls and loop through controls to delete them. Or if you want to delete specific controls than in loop check type of control and delete it.

Comment: @DDave yeah if it is possible, or any other way to delete multiple controls with just 1 button.

Comment: what kind of application is this? winforms/wpf?

Comment: Windows Form Application @un-lucky

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this; Iterate through available controls and delete Delete according to the condition

```
foreach (Control ctrl in this.Controls.OfType<Control>().ToList())
{
    if ((ctrl.GetType() == typeof(TextBox) || ctrl.GetType() == typeof(ComboBox))
        && ctrl.Tag.ToString() == btn.Tag.ToString())
    {
        ctrl.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Comment: This is not correct, you are modifying the collection you are iterating.  This bug will cause controls to be skipped, it can't find one that's after the one that's is disposed.  You must make a copy of the collection or iterate backwards.

Comment: @HansPassant: Brilliant spot `it can't find one that's after the one that's is disposed.` i will check try to find solution and update the answer- Thank you

Comment: Just use `this.Controls.OfType<Control>().ToList()` for the quick fix.

Comment: @HansPassant: thank you for the new information; i have updated the answer

Answer (score -1):

You can simply do

```
this.Controls.Remove(btn);
```

Or if you want to remove all

```
this.Controls.RemoveAll();
```

Don't forget that controls are in containers so you can also do this to delete all siblings

```
btn.Parent.Controls.RemoveAll();
```